# Converting Dictionary<Int, Object> To Dictionary<Int, Object.Property> with lambdas

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a class Building with properties int Id, int Height, int NumberOfFloors.

If I have a Dictionary, where each key is the building id. Is there a way to convert this into a Dictionary where each key is the building Id, and each value is the number of floors. Obviously this is feasible with a loop. Just wondering if there is a simple way to do this using lambdas?

Thanks!

```
var intToBuilding = new Dictionary<int, Building>(); //pretend populated
var intToInt = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach(var intBuilding in intToBuilding)
{
  var building = userPreference.Value;
  intToInt.Add(intBuilding.Key, building.Height);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It should go something like:

```
var floorDictionary = buildingDictionary
   .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value.NumberofFloors);
```

The source dictionary implements `IEnumerable< KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> >` and for that there is an extension method `ToDictionary(keySelector, valueSelector)`.